"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" What does this build error mean?
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
  Build file 'D:\\Unity\\Project\\My project\\New Project\\Library\\Bee\\Android\\Prj\\IL2CPP\\Gradle\\launcher\\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Cannot parse project property android.enableR8='' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s


UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
This build error message appears. How do I fix it?
I see an error message when building with Unity, but I'm a Unity beginner so I don't know what it means.

Just do one thing android.enableR8=false from your gradle.properties and sync project again it will work.

I solved this problem.
Just two slashes, //.
//UTF=8
That's it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Instead of commenting it out, I changed it to true and the error disappeared.

I solved this problem.
Just two slashes, //.
//UTF=
That's it.
If you build with a new build number, this error message will appear again. A beginner like me doesn't know how to prevent this, but in that case, you can solve it by commenting it out again using //.

Instead of commenting it out, I changed it to
android.enableR8=true and the error disappeared.
